# Zoom in out a view to a specific point iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation

I want to zoom in and out a UIVIew on to specific point something similer effect to focus + zoom in. I don't want to use UISCrollView. What is the right approach to do this if anyone could suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is to use a scroll view. If you don't want to use a scroll view, though, you can use a tiled layer. Bill Dudney has an example of that here: http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/tiledlayer_on_the_iphone

Why don't you want to use a scroll view?

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I don't you want to use a scroll view because I have other objects on view and i need touch of them.